# Would barium get me in trouble in airport security?

Tags: airport-security

I have recently gotten a barium swallow test for my dysphagia. The radiologist said it would pass in about 3 days. The problem is that I would still have it in my system when traveling to the airport. Would this set any alarms off? If so, how do I prove I'm innocent?

Comment: Barium isn't hot, you won't set off any radiation alarms.  You basically have a temporary piece of metal inside you, that's all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No, a barium meal will not set off alarms.**

Lots of security places have radiation detectors, and they are set to detect very low levels of radiation. From personal experience they can detect a "radioactive stress test" a few days after it happens.

However a barium meal is not a "radioactive stress test" and is not significantly radioactive, compared to, say, a banana.

If you are X-rayed at the airport, the residual barium might conceivably show up. A letter from your doctor should be enough to ensure you don't actually 'get in trouble' because of it.

Comment: A barium meal does not work through barium being radioactive. It works because barium is radioopaque, meaning that X rays cannot pass through it. The radioactivity of barium is not zero but is extremely low. I am surprised you imply that it can be detected by radiation detectors several days later. Are you sure you don't mean X ray machines?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt is right. Barium is ___not___ radioactive (for any practical purpose; Ba-130 comprises 0.1% and has a half-life exceeding a  sextillion years, Ba-132 comprises another 0.1% and is "observationally stable", the remaining 99.8% is in non-radioactive isotopes, [source here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_barium))! No radiation is emitted from the barium. Barium is used as a [radiocontrast agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocontrast_agent). If the airport takes an X-ray of you, they will see (beside your bones etc.) something opaque inside your digestive tract.

Comment: I apologize, on further investigation it seems that the test I remembered wasn't a barium meal, but a radioactive stress test. If Connor Belli would care to unaccept the answer I will delete it.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it. Just edit. Their machines do use X-Rays, right? So something out of the ordinary could still show up. Getting a doctor's note if you're worried they might have questions could still be good advice.

Comment: They don't X-Ray people... Unless OP is travelling inside a luggage.

Comment: "Unless OP is travelling inside a luggage" - wait, there's another way? I guess whole my life I've been doing it wrong...

Comment: The suggestion to get a letter from the physician in charge is a good one.

Comment: @Antzi depends on where you are. The whole body scanners in use in some places indeed use low intensity X-rays to penetrate clothing but not penetrate deep under the skin.

Comment: @Antzi They will x-ray you if they think you are carrying drugs internally.

Comment: @Antzi What do the imaging devices (considered to be very invasive by some) use? And perhaps more importantly, could they pick up barium?